# Reading the first 10 bytes of a file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, hex

```
    for (String name : filenames) {   
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input.readUTF());   
    int byteCounter = 0;   
    int rowCounter = 0;   
    long bufferCounter = 0;   
    byte[] b = new byte[8];   
    int read;   

    //in.skip(10);   
    //while((read = in.read()) != -1){   
    while((read = in.read(b, 0, 10)) != -1){   
        byteCounter ++;   
        if (byteCounter != 1000){   
            if (rowCounter == 16){   
                System.out.println("\n");   
                rowCounter = 0;   
            }   
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(read) + "\t");   
            bufferCounter ++;   
            rowCounter ++;   
        }else{   
                byteCounter = 0;   
                try{   
                    Thread.sleep(200);   
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {   
                }   
        }   
    }   
    System.out.println("\n"+"================"+"\n");   
}
```

Hi there, I was hoping someone might be able to help me with an issue I've been having. I'm trying to get my program to read in the first 10 bytes of a specified file. I can get it to work with the skip() but obviously this does the opposite of what I want (it removes the first 10 instead) 
I've looked all over to no avail, if you can help me out, that'd be great. 
You can probably see that I've tried to enter the read(b, off, len) into the code already but this just produces random characters as an output rather than the actual hex characters I want 74 65 71 etc (Edit: These random characters seem to be the hex code for the number of bytes read. So for a text file that has 23 hex chars in it, it produces a a 3 (or in other words: 10,10,3 = 23)

Comment: I'm quite sure it fails in case of `in.read(b, 0, 10)` reading less than 10 bytes. It practically never happens, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: I see my previous comment may not be clear: I mean: It practically never happens *in case there are more bytes available*, since data get transfered from the disk in multiples of sector size.

Comment: :S That has completely lost me now. Are you saying there is something wrong with/missing from my coding? Sorry to have to ask, but you know...

Comment: The other way round, you code lost me. `read` is the number of bytes read, it may be anything between 1 and 10. You titled the question `Reading the first 10 bytes of a file` but you do read some random number of bytes repeatedly. Your byte counter count reads instead of bytes. So **do you really want to read the first 10 bytes of a file**? If so, then look at my answer, otherwise consider renaming the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here

```
System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(read) + "\t");
```

`read` contains the number of bytes effectively read from stream. Teh bytes are in array `b`.

By the way: your array has a size of 8. you should increas it to 10 if you want to read 10 bytes!

Comment: Hey lweller, thanks for responding so quickly. Yeah, I noticed the 8 thing (that's just me messing around desperately trying to get it to work lol) I've tried changing it so it now says System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b) + "\t"); but that produces an error  "toHexString(int) in java.lang.Integer cannot be applied to (byte[])"

Comment: try to use [encodeHexString(byte)](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHexString(byte[])) from [apache commons codec lib](http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi)

Comment: Where exactly would the encodeHexString(b) part go? Sorry if that seems like a stupid question but I've tried putting it in the system.out.println part and other locations too, but to no avail :S

Comment: you have to download and add to your classpath the apache commons doced lib and then write somthing like `System.out.print(org.apache.commons.codec.binary .Hex.encodeHexString(b)  + "\t");`

Comment: Thanks for sticking around lweller, really appreciate it. Right, goen to the link you sent, downloaded the commons-codec-1.4-bin.zip file into my downloads folder, unzipped it and it's currently just sat in my downloads folder. I'm guessing it has to go to the java section in the program files but short of that, I've got no idea. I'm a uni student and we've never had to do anything like this so sorry if its a stupid question to ask :)

Comment: If it helps, in the program files/java/ folder I have "jdk1.6.0_23" and "jre6". I'm using JCreator LE too.

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];
new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(input.readUTF())).readFully(b);
```

This is the simplest way, but it throws in case there are less than 10 bytes available. In case you don't want it, use a loop. Somehow I don't get what you're doing, it really doesn't look like reading the first 10 bytes: `if (byteCounter != 1000)`