# Where do you add 'commons-codec-1.4.jar' to if you want access to encodeHexString etc?

Tags: java, hex, apache-commons

Hey, this question links into another post  I made today: [Reading the first 10 bytes of a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767470/reading-the-first-10-bytes-of-a-file-in-java)

Having been told that my solution could involve the apache commons codec library, I've tried to figure out where the file needs to be placed and am seriously not getting it. Can't find anything online that simply says 'It goes here...' so maybe someone on here can help?

I've got Windows 7, I'm using JCreator and have the 'jre6' and 'jdk1.6.0_23' folders in my Program Files/Java folder

Any help at all would be appreciated so please let me know :)

Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the jar file (*not* the containing directory) via your class path (a list of directories and .jar files)

e.g. from a command line:

```
$ java -cp {complete path to jar file} YourClass
```

Alternatively you can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) for more details.

Comment: Can I be honest and probably sound like a total noob...what? lol I'm not much of a java programmer so if you can explain it as basically as possible, I'd REALLY appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, although if I'm honest, I found a way in JCreator to add in additional librarys which seems to have worked but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Most (probably all) IDEs will manage external libraries for you.  The IDE will add the library to the classpath internally when running/debugging your program.  However, if you intend to distribute your program for execution outside the IDE, you will have to understand how to reference the library.

Answer (score 0):

You may also specified globally CLASSPATH environment variable i.e:

unix:
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar1.jar:/path/to/jar2.jar: ...

windows:
set CLASSPATH=c:/path/to/jar1.jar;c:/path/to/jar2.jar

Remember on windows classpath separator is ";" and on unix/linux it is ":".

It is also correct for -cp option mentioned in previous answer by Brian

Comment: I think I've figured it out, although if I'm honest, I found a way in JCreator to add in additional librarys which seems to have worked but thanks for the help anyway.